# Elementary row operations that obtains the Hermite normal form of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, hermite-normal-form

This article says that the elementary operations required are **unimodular** transformations. My questions are the following:

- **Why** does it have to be **unimodular**? What is so special about it?
- **Why** are the elementary operations called "unimodular transformations"?

Since unimodular matrix is defined to be ***a square integer matrix having determinant +1 or -1***, then would unimodular transformation mean that it transforms some matrx $M$ to have unimodular properties? (*Does this answer my 2nd question?*)

- **What** is the significance of a unimodular transformation and hermite
  normal form? In particular, **why** would someone want to transform their matrix in hermite normal form? Like most of us know gaussian elimination computes for solutions, and reduced row echelon form help us determine if the vectors are linearly independent.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `unimodular matrix` of dimension $n$ with coefficients in a (commutative) ring $R$ is simply an element of the group  $ \operatorname{GL}(n,R)$, i.e. an invertible matrix,such that its inverse has coefficients in $R$.

The condition is this
$$U\in \operatorname{GL}(n,R)\iff \det U\in R^\times \enspace (\text{the group of units in  }R).$$
 So here, with matrices with coefficients in $\mathbf Z$, it means that $\det U=\pm 1$.

When you transform a matrix $A$ by a unimodular transformation $U$, so that $H=UA$, you can do the backwards transformation: $A=U^{-1}H$, since $U$ is invertible and $U^{-1}$ is unimodular.

Comment: group of units in $R$. According to wikipedia this has something to do with Rings. I haven't read up on any ring theory yet.

Comment: You just have to know what a ring is , to understand this: the group  of units is the set of elements in $R$ which have a multiplicative inverse (if we have a field, it's the non-zero elements, by definition). These form a multiplicative group.

Comment: What does matrix $A$ got to do in the condition you've given?

Comment: Sorry, a bad copy-paste. I'll fix it at once.

Comment: Okay. But I think I am missing the point on why the facts you've given makes unimodular transformation important. If I already have matrix $A$, then why would I like to construct the unimodular matrix $U$ to obtain $H$?

Comment: I can only give a general answer: it's for problems over integers and  you do not always have a change of basis matrix to solve linear equations as if it were a problem over $\mathbf Q$. It seems Hermite normal form is the equivalent of the row reduced echelon form over fields.

Comment: alright. I'll just accept your answer then. thanks.